# How to get rid of lines in the lattice arrangeGrob

Tags: r, lattice, gridextra

I am using the `arrangeGrob` function, but it is drawing annoying lines - tile pattern in the background:

[image]

## How do I get rid of the pattern, and draw clean white background everywhere? (Not grey)?

My code:

```
L <- c()
i <- 1
for (v in ...) { # simplified code here with ...
    p1 <- spplot(...)
    L[[i]] <- p1
    i <- i + 1
}


require(gridExtra)
png(filename = paste0("env-", env_variant, "-2-vars_maps.png"), width = 1280, height = 1792, pointsize = 20)
x <- arrangeGrob(grobs = L, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, padding = unit(2, "line"))
plot(x)
dev.off()
```

Comment: dont use `plot` use `grid.draw`

Comment: @user2957945 Wow, amazing!! Does the job! Thanks a lot! You can post it as an answer! :-)